# Why does using the true value of the iterator err?

Tags: c++

I am instantiating an iterator within a method in one of my templates. It works when I use `auto` to dynamically obtain type information:

```
auto itr = my_list.cbegin();
```

However, I get a compile-time error when I use the actual type:

```
typedef InternalEdge network_internal_edge_type;
typedef std::shared_ptr< network_internal_edge_type > network_shared_edge_ptr;
typedef std::list< network_shared_edge_ptr > network_internal_edge_store_type;

network_internal_edge_store_type::const_iterator itr = internal_edges_.cbegin();
```

`InternalEdge` is a private class I had defined somewhere above in the code.
Here is the error:

```
Network.hpp:411:5: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘Network<V>::internal_edge_store_mechanism:: const_iterator’ because ‘Network<V>::internal_edge_store_mechanism’ is a dependent scope
Network.hpp:411:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘itr’
Network.hpp:412:12: error: ‘itr’ was not declared in this scope
```

Why does using `auto` make the code work? Why does the compiler think I need "typename"?

Comment: Because it's dependent name in template-function. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: Wow, that is actually a very useful compiler error. May I ask which compiler/version you are using?

Comment: @juanchopanza: looks like a relatively recent GCC.

Comment: @Fanael Ah OK, I guess I haven't triggered that kind of error recently then. Thanks for the info.